# Pass image objects through shiny but outside renderPlot

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

I have a shiny app that uses `fileInput` and `magick` to read a user chosen image, and display it as a ggplot.

```
library(shiny)
library(magick)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(


   titlePanel(""),


   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("current_image", "Choose image file")),


      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("current_image_plot")
      )
   )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$current_image_plot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$current_image)
    myplot <- magick::image_read(input$current_image$datapath)
    myplot <- image_ggplot(myplot)
    return(myplot)
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, I'd like to separate the logic of reading the image, from the logic of plotting the image. I tried putting the `image_read` inside its own `observeEvent`, but this threw the error `The 'image' argument is not a magick image object.`

I know that when I print `class(myplot)` within the `observeEvent`, it returns a `magick-image` object, so what has changed by the time I'm trying to access `active_image`?

```
library(shiny)
library(magick)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(


   titlePanel(""),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("current_image", "Choose image file")),


      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("current_image_plot")
      )
   )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  active_image <- observeEvent(input$current_image, {
    req(input$current_image)
    myplot <- magick::image_read(input$current_image$datapath)
    return(myplot)
  })

  output$current_image_plot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$current_image)
    myplot <- image_ggplot(active_image)
    return(myplot)
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `observeEvent` does not return an object. Use `eventReactive` instaed, that is, replace

```
  active_image <- observeEvent(input$current_image, {
    req(input$current_image)
    myplot <- magick::image_read(input$current_image$datapath)
    return(myplot)
  })
```

with

```
  active_image <- eventReactive(input$current_image, {
    req(input$current_image)
    myplot <- magick::image_read(input$current_image$datapath)
    return(myplot)
  })
```

or more concisely:

```
  active_image <- eventReactive(input$current_image, {
    req(input$current_image)
    magick::image_read(input$current_image$datapath)
  })
```

Now, `active_image` is a reactive conductor, it is not the value returned. You have to do `active_image()` to get the returned value:

```
  output$current_image_plot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$current_image)
    image_ggplot(active_image())
  })
```